# How do I right-align more than 1 menu item in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

for only 1 right-aligned menu item I have found this solution:

[How do I right-align the 'help' menu item in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3023638/how-do-i-right-align-the-help-menu-item-in-wpf)

Is there a solution if I want more than 1 menu item right-aligned:

```
Program | View |                            Edit | File | ...
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Did you try giving all menu items `HorizontalAlignment="Right"`?

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc Yes, but it only works for the last item

Comment: This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24127129/wpf-menu-item-right-alignment) may help you . You achieve it by using dockpanel

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3023891/3283203) which you link does in fact have almost the solution.

The key resides in the ItemPanelTemplate HorizontalAlignement property!

```
<Menu HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <Menu.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <DockPanel HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Menu.ItemsPanel>
    <MenuItem Header="File"/>
    <MenuItem Header="Edit"/>
</Menu>
```

However, if you indeed want 2 or mores items to the left AND to the right, you will need some hacky solutions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3023814/3283203), which requires the number of items to be constant.

Comment: How strange, it did for me. I'm editing to show the full Menu XAML.